# How to display multiple JSON objects in an ejs tag

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

I am making a table using NodeJS/JS/HTML/CSS/EJS. I want the table to be able to show to JSON objects in one column. When I use the code below, it runs fine, but it only prints out the second object given, not both.

Example: I am trying to print out the first and last name on one line, but it only shows the last name on the page (I'm assuming it's writing the firstName, but then overwriting it with the lastName.)

```
<div>
<table>
    <% data2.forEach(function(person) {%>
        <tr><td id="<%= person["ID"]%>"><%= person["firstName", "lastName"] %>
    <% }); %></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out for all who our interested in the future... Simple mistake

```
<div>
<table>
<% data2.forEach(function(person) {%>
    <tr><td id="<%= person["ID"]%>"><%= person["firstName"] %> <%= person["lastName"] %>
<% }); %></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```